# Excel VBA Moving all images

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Im using incrementleft in Excel 2016 to move all images named "Bullet"

Code:

```
    Worksheets("Fighter Game").Shapes("Bullet").IncrementLeft 18.75
```

But the code just move the first-made image.
So how can we fix it so it will move all the images?

Comment: You are just moving the shape called `Bullet`. You have to loop through all shapes. Start by reading about the [For Each loop](http://www.homeandlearn.org/for_each.html) and see if you can make it work. If not, update your question and I'm sure you will get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `For Each` loop to find all the shapes named Bullet and move these

```
Sub MoveImages()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In Worksheets("Fighter Game").Shapes
        If s.Name = "Bullet" Then
            s.IncrementLeft 18.75
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```